# Security concern on locally stored authentication token

Tags: authentication, mobile, token, mobile-app

It is a common method on mobile applications to allow users to bypass authentication process by verifying a locally stored token (previously authenticated) on device.

This is to strike a balance between usability (avoiding authentication every time) and security.

1. Are there any security holes in this process?
2. What are measures to be taken to strengthen this method?

Comment: With my knowledge in the android sphere: the storage of banking app data on old versions of android was a reason for the push to a more robust file system and stricter app containerization. Even then, you could view your question as web browser cookies. They aren't encrypted but generally expire in short periods of time. It isn't expected for local software to steal these cookies anyways.

Comment: Understood the web cookies, I'm referring to the authentication token with more life time stored in local mobile storage.